# Reading text in textarea line by line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I am using textarea to take user input. and want to read line by line.
But it's not displaying anything
I want to make a comma seperated list of the text in different lines

**JS:**

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
    string = document.getElementById("hi").val();
    alert(string); 
    var html="";
    var lines = $('#id').val().split('\n');
    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
        //code here using lines[i] which will give you each line
        html+=lines[i];
        html+=",";
    }
    $("#inthis").html(string);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="hi" name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="enter one wdg in one line" ></textarea>

<input type="button" value="test" />
<div id="inthis"></div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1077/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's updated js...

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1084/)

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
    var html = "";
    var lines = $('#hi').val().split('\n');
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        //code here using lines[i] which will give you each line
        html += lines[i];
        html += ",";
    }
    html = html.substring(0,html.length-1);
    $("#inthis").html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have a confused mix of native javascript and jQuery code in your example. A native DOM element has no `val()` method for example, that's jQuery. Secondly, you could massively simplify your code by just using `split()` and `join(',')`. Try this:

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
    var string = $("#hi").val().split('\n').join(',');
    $("#inthis").html(string);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/pUeue/1089/)

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is a Jquery function, you will have to convert the DOM element to jquery obj or use `.value`

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
  string = $(document.getElementById("hi")).val();
  string = string.replace("\n", ",")
  $("#inthis").html(string);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1090/

Comment: Thanks, but the fiddle doesnt show the comma seperated list.. Well, probably .split('\n') isnt used

Comment: oh yea, for comma you can just replace the \n with ',' without using split and join! I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Change:**

```
string = document.getElementById("hi").val();
```

**TO**

```
string = document.getElementById("hi").value;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/pUeue/1079/)

Answer (score 0):

there is mistake in second line u have used jQuery val instead of value so try below:-

```
string = document.getElementById("hi").value;
```

and need to put the below line before you load the string in div.:-

```
html = html.substring(0,html.length-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1085/

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
    string = $(document.getElementById("hi")).val();
    alert(string); 
    var htmlD="";
    var lines = string.split('\n');
    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
    //code here using lines[i] which will give you each line
    htmlD+=lines[i];
    htmlD+=",";
}
    $("#inthis").html(htmlD);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1080/.

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
    string = $("#hi").val();
    alert(string); 
    var html="";
    var lines = $('#hi').val().split('\n');
    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++) {
        //code here using lines[i] which will give you each line
        html+=lines[i];
        html+=",";
    }
    $("#inthis").html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
    var lines =  $('#hi').val().split(/\n/);
    $("#inthis").html(lines.join(","));
});
```